# How can I send jqgrid data by ajax post method to the server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I haven't found how to send programatically with jquery all the rows in the jqgrid for be processed in the server.

I've only found one method called getRowData(id) but it doesn't helpme because i don't have the id. that's why i want to send all the data

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: hmmm, this sounds like a strange approach. Do you really want to send individual rows back to the server, and just resorting to all rows because you can't find how to do one? If so I can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jQuery to traverse the table and get the id for each row.

```
tmp = [];    
jQuery("#data > tbody > tr").each(function (){
        tmp[this.id] = jQuery("#data").getRowData(this.id);
    });
```

My table id is 'data' in this case.

Answer (score 0):

post data send to server

```
jQuery('#list').setPostData(data[]);
```

remember config jqgrid -> mtype: 'POST',